# Tablesorter: How to exclude row when use widget filter

Tags: tablesorter

With tablesorter : `http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Introduction`

And with this example : `http://jsfiddle.net/w1e2x6cz/1/`

How i can exclude all value who are in the row of the first body in the select filter ?

For example my first select filter contains this values:

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc
- Total

And i want only :

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the "Total" row ignored, you'll need to modify the "tablesorter-no-sort" class name of that info-only tbody in the options:

```
cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort"
```

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/w1e2x6cz/2/).